# Rails - displaying users with intersecting properties from 2 different join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, intersection

I'm a beginner so the title of my question probably isn't very clear. For that reason, it has been difficult to find any solutions to the problem I'm having. I'm working on a language learning app that allows users to connect with native speakers who want to learn their language i.e. a native English speaker who is learning Italian and Spanish will be able to connect with native Italian and Spanish speakers who want to learn English.

I have a Language table that has the language name as a string and 2 join tables: Native and Desired. These both take user_id and language_id.

My models are set up like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :natives
  has_many :native_languages, through: :natives, source: :language

  has_many :desireds
  has_many :desired_languages, through: :desireds, source: :language
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :native_speakers, through: :native_languages, source: :natives
    has_many :desired_speakers, through: :desired_languages, source: :desireds
end

class Native < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :language
end

class Desired < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :language
end
```

I want to display matched users on the User index, so I need help with the query that should go within the index method on the users controller.

This is my first post here so let me know if I missed any critical pieces. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subquery.

**Native Speakers I desired**

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
desired_lanuages = user.desired_languages
User.where(id: Native.select(:user_id).where(language: desired_lanuages))
```

**Who want me**

```
native_language = user.native_languages
User.where(id: Desired.select(:user_id).where(language: native_language))
```

**Match**

```
User.where(id: Native.select(:user_id).where(language: desired_lanuages))
  .where(id: Desired.select(:user_id).where(language: native_language))
```

I do not try running code. But I think that kind of code is possible

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response Jaehyun! Aside from a few misspellings it works : )  I'll post the code below as it might help someone else.